# Finding slope at a point in a direction on a 3d surface

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives

This is not a duplicate, I have attempted the question and am not sure why my answer is incorrect.

QUESTION: The surface with equation $z = x^3 +xy^2 $ intersects the plane with equation $ 2x−2y = 1$ in a curve. What is the slope of that curve when $ x=1 $ and $ y= 1/2 $ ?

Since the line $ 2x - 2y = 1 \space $ travels in the direction $ e_{1} + e_{2} $

we can say $ x = 1 + t $ and $ y = \frac{1}{2} + t $

We then substitute this into the equation and differentiate with respect to $t$. Finally we find the limit of this function as $ t \rightarrow 0 $.

So writing the function in terms of $t$ we get:

$ (t+1)^{3} + (t+1)(t+ \frac{1}{2})^{2} $

$ =  2t^{3} + 5t^{2} + \frac{17t}{4} + 5/4 $

Differentiating this wrt $t$ we get:

$ 6t^{2} + 10t + \frac{17}{4} $

Finding the limit as $ t \rightarrow 0 $ we get $ \frac{17}{4} $

However the answer is supposed to be $ \frac{17}{ \frac{4}{\sqrt{2} } } $

I realise to get the directional derivative we must divide the vector by it's length to find the equivalent unit vector. In this case $ e_{1} + e_{2}  $ is $ \sqrt{1+1} = \sqrt{2} $

However when I enter any constant times $t$ (i.e- $ x = 1+2t $) I still get $ \frac{17}{4} $ as my final answer.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong and explain to me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is totally correct. You need to normalize the direction along the plane is travelling. Since the length of $e_1+e_2$ is $\sqrt{2}$ you have $x(t)=1+\sqrt{2}t$ and $y(t)=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2}t$. If you plug that into $z$ and differentiate with respect to $t$ at $t=0$, then you get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That makes complete sense what you are saying. However the answer i get is $ \frac{17 \sqrt{2}}{4} $ which is not supposed to be right, can you confirm that this is definitely the right answer?

Comment: $\frac{17\sqrt{2}}{4}=\frac{17}{\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}}$ :)

Comment: Whoops... that was embarrassing

Comment: @John Doe: Would you please be so kind, to write down your complete tangent-vector? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

We use this surface

$f(x,y)=x^3+x y^2$

and we use this plane

$2 x-2 y=1$

The curve

$\alpha (s)=\frac{1 }{\sqrt{2}}s(1,1)+(1,\frac{1}{2})$

lives in the plane. The velocity is given by:

$\dot{\alpha }(s)$=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)$.

Using the graph of $f$, we get:

$\varphi (u,v)=(u,v,f(u,v))$.

Along our curve $\alpha$, this is a curve, say $\beta$

$\beta(s)=\varphi (\alpha(s))=(\alpha ^1(s),\alpha ^2(s),f(\alpha(s)))$

which lives in the graph of $f$.

Velocity of $\beta$ is

$$\dot{\beta }(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(1,1,3 s^2+5 \sqrt{2} s+\frac{17}{4}\right)$$.

For $s=0$, we have

$\beta(0)=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{4})$, our point of interest and

velocity:

$$\dot{\beta }(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1,\frac{17}{4})$$.

So $$\dot{\alpha }(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)$$

has unit length. Differentiation part is straight forward.
Velocity for $\dot{\beta }(0)$ is different from that, what
it "should" be. Here is plot:

[image]

Pink one is $\alpha$,  red one is $\beta$.

For $\alpha (s)=\sqrt{2}s(1,1)+(1,\frac{1}{2})$
I get $$\dot{\beta }(0)=\sqrt{2}\left(1,1,\frac{17}{4}\right)$$

but $\dot{\alpha }$ is not of unit-length.